# object reference not set to an instance of an object. MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't know why it's `null` but I pass a value in the controller but it's not passing it to the view

**View:**

```
@model LABEX7_GUINTUJOSHUA.Models.DataModel1
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "HomePage";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.name</h2>
```

**Controller:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using LABEX7_GUINTUJOSHUA.Models;

namespace LABEX7_GUINTUJOSHUA.Controllers
{
    public class DataModel1Controller : Controller
    {
        // GET: DataModel1
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DataModel1 user = new DataModel1()
            {
                name = "Joshua Guintu"
            };


            return View(user);
        }
        public ActionResult HomePage()
        {


            return View();
        }
    }

}
```

**Model:**

```
namespace LABEX7_GUINTUJOSHUA.Models
{
    public class DataModel1
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
    }
```

Please check the error in this link
[ERORR PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxpdB.png)

Comment: `return View();` - if you pass nothing, what do you expect?

Comment: Voting to close, you just didn't pass an instance of DataModel1 to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're accessing the `HomePage`, you need to create an instance of the object pass the model to the `HomePage`, not just Index.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   DataModel1 user = new DataModel1()
   {
      name = "Joshua Guintu"
   };
   return View(user);
}

public ActionResult HomePage()
{
   DataModel1 user = new DataModel1()
   {
      name = "Joshua Guintu"
   };
   return View(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing page Homepage and in Homepage View there you are accessing model (DataModel1) and from Homepage Action method you havent passed the model as parameter